# Как настроить ширину TextField kivymd

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Понимаю, вопрос может звучать довольно глупо, но как изменить длину виджета textfield в kivymd? Я не нашел аргумента, отвечающего за этот параметр

```
MDTextField:
       width: 10
```

Вроде этого, но используя этот аргумент длина не меняется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Как я понял нужно указать этот параметр size_hint_x значение None
Перед этим width: 120

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    padding: "5dp"

    MDTextField:
        id: text_field_error
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 120
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        self.screen.ids.text_field_error.bind(
            on_text_validate=self.set_error_message,
            on_focus=self.set_error_message,
    )
        return self.screen

    def set_error_message(self, instance_textfield):
        self.screen.ids.text_field_error.error = True


Test().run()
```